# HTTPUrlConnection GET

Tags: java, android, json, get, httpurlconnection

I am having some difficulty receiving the JSON list response from a given URL in my Android application. I am not sure if I am missing a step in firing the GET call, or the problem is on the web service side. Right when the code gets to the "getInputStream" line, it crashes

```
    if (url != null)  {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            System.out.println(response.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The errors given are as follows have to do with NetworkOnMainThread Exceptions as well as a few others. **Note**: This is within a method that is called in the "onCreate" method, which could also be a source of the problem.

Comment: Try commenting out the setRequestMethod.  I'm fairly certain that the connection defaults to GET.

Comment: Didn't work... I wonder if maybe I should put it in an ASyncTask and give it a try that way?

Comment: NetworkOnMainThread, put it in an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Alright it ended up being the last issue, thanks for the clarification Daniel. I got lazy and did not put it in an ASyncTask. Works great now, thanks!